# Python - 'module' object is not callable returned when calling function

Tags: python, function, module

I am pretty new to Python, just learning it, and I am having trouble running my functions. I have a bit of a background in Matlab, so that may be where some of my confusion is coming from.

This is the code that I have written in a script, using Notepad++ on my PC:

```
def print_order_numbers(amount):

    i = 0
    numbers = []

    while i < amount:
        print("At the top i is %d" %i)
        numbers.append(i)

        i = i + 1
        print ("Numbers now: ", numbers)
        print("at the bottom i si %d" %i)

    print ("the numbers: ")

    for num in numbers:
        print (num)
```

Then when in python, after loading the function using:

```
from filename import print_order_numbers
```

However, because the function itself doesn't return anything and wasn't given an argument, this doesn't do anything. So when I try and call the function, like this:

```
print_order_numbers(2)
```

it gives me the error traceback:
File "", line 1, in 
NameError: name 'print_order_numbers' is not defined

I have found that if I put this call in the same script as the function is written it, when I import the function, it runs it correctly. Why is my function recognized as a module by Python, and why does calling the function inside the script work?

Is there any way to call the function in the python command window directly without having to put the call in the script where the function is? Matlab's functions allows you to do this and it would make things a lot easier, if I wanted to call a function from another script. (or would I just have to have the function in the same script as the rest of the code which calls upon it?)

Sorry if this is a basic question, I just wish to understand this subject better, and have not been able to find a straight answer in all of the questions/tutorials I've looked through. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You have a module called `print_order_numbers`, try printing `print_order_numbers.__file__`

Comment: please [edit] your question and post the **full text** of any traceback or error you are getting

Comment: So there is no error on the import? Only on the call. Do you have an `__init__.py` in the directory?

Comment: I should not have an     __init__.py in the same file/directory as the script that this function is in. Although I understand that it sets apart a module and a package, I don't really know what this is, can you @PaulRooney help me out with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the name of your file print_order_numbers.py? If so, you need to change the name. The interpreter thinks you are referring to the module rather than the function.

If that isn't it, you could try

```
import filename
filename.print_order_numbers(2)
```

Failing that, you need to provide more context as others have stated.

Comment: Using 'file.filename.print_order_numbers(2)' worked after importing the file. But why do you think using 'from file import filename' and then calling the function 'print_order_numbers(2)' did not work? It gave me the callback error "name 'print_order_numbers' is not defined. Thanks!